# Как вызвать python скрипт из php на хостинге

Tags: php, python

Писал сайт на локальном сервере(OpenServer) из php запускал python следующим образом:

```
exec('C:\python\mypython\python.exe W:\domains\magnetic\main_parse.py', $parse)
```

Лучше ничего не придумал)

Сейчас поставил сайт на хостинг(Хостинг reg.ru, панель управления ispmanager) и, разумеется , всё сломалось.

Вопрос такой: как на хостинге запускать файлы python из php, питон должен принимать одну переменную и отдавать массив строк.

Comment: Точно так же как на винде

Comment: У вас скорее всего в настройках apache стоит access deny для каталога `cgi-bin`. И, возможно, нельзя переопределить эти настойки через файл `.htaccess`

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, Апач у вас будет запускать и обрабатывать запросы для передачи Питон-обработчику, либо вы сами это будете делать из PHP. Если второе - то кроме exec в PHP вам ничего больше не потребуется (за исключением необходимости убедиться что из консольной строки на сервере можно запустить `python main_parse.py`). Тогда уже вам нужно будет добавить параметры для файла, ну и соответственно ответ скрипта. Смотрите [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781768/executing-python-script-with-php-variables/19781913) с англоязычного SO

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался)